# New Order Emails Sendig Two Times

Tags: magento-2.2.5, order-email

I am facing issue with new order emails. Magento send new order emails two times for every order.

I am not getting what is issue there.

Answer (score 0):

create custom plugin to check if the email has been already sent or not and only sent an email if its not sent before

create module.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="rahul_Sendorderplugin" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'rahul_Sendorderplugin',
    __DIR__
);
```

in di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender" type="rahul\Sendorderplugin\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender"></preference>
</config>
```

Ordersender.php

```
<?php
namespace rahul\Sendorderplugin\Model\Order\Email\Sender

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class OrderSender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender
{

    public function send(Order $order, $forceSyncMode = false)
    {
        $order->setSendEmail(true);

        if (!$this->globalConfig->getValue('sales_email/general/async_sending') || $forceSyncMode) {

//$order->getEmailSent() will check if the email has been sent for order or not


            if ($this->checkAndSend($order) && !$order->getEmailSent()) {
                $order->setEmailSent(true);
                $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, ['send_email', 'email_sent']);
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            $order->setEmailSent(null);
            $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, 'email_sent');
        }

        $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, 'send_email');

        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you and let me know if you got any issues. I will be happy to help.
This is the directory structure ->

[image]

Comment: tried this but Not working :(

Comment: sorry to hear that ,just wanted to confirm you must have enabled the module and also executed setup:di:compile command and cleaned cache. I was also facing the same issue and solved out using the same.

Comment: I have checked all things

Comment: not sure than :(

Comment: you should have the directory structure like the image I have added in the answer for your new extension.

Answer (score 0):

I have debugged it and found solution after lots of debugging.

Issue was occurred due to Paytm payment module. It was also overriding code to send Emails.

I have disabled Paytm module and now issue resolved.